# Error in example from book - 'placeholder' is not implemented as a property of 'el' in 'if ( !el.placeholder )'

Tags: javascript

This is a Placeholder Polyfill script example from book 'JavaScript & jQuery - Interactive Front-End'

[image]

In the highlighted script line numbered as (7) in the pic, condition (!el.placeholder) inside 'if' depends on 'placeholder' being a implemented as a property of element 'el' so that it can have falsy or truthy values. While the basis of this script is to run only when browser does not support 'placeholder' property in form elements, it seems to me as an incorrect example.

I am a still a novice self-learner web developer. I just want to make sure if I am correct and this example is wrong according to my understanding. And if I am wrong (book is correct) please kindly explain in detail.

Here is the sample code (from pic):

```
    (function() {                                        // Place code in an IIFE
  // Test: Create an input element, and see if the placeholder is supported
  if ('placeholder' in document.createElement('input')) {
    return;
  }

  var length = document.forms.length;               // Get number of forms
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {               // Loop through each one - updated shorter syntax
    showPlaceholder(document.forms[i].elements);    // Call showPlaceholder()
  }

  function showPlaceholder(elements) {              // Declare function
    for (var i = 0, l = elements.length; i < l; i++) { // For each element
      var el = elements[i];                         // Store that element

      if (!el.placeholder) {                        // If no placeholder set
        continue;                                   // Go to next element
      }                                             // Otherwise

      el.style.color = '#666666';                      // Set text to gray
      el.value = el.placeholder;                    // Add placeholder text

      addEvent(el, 'focus', function () {           // If it gains focus
        if (this.value === this.placeholder) {      // If value=placeholder 
          this.value = '';                          // Empty text input
          this.style.color = '#000000';                // Make text black
        }
      });

      addEvent(el, 'blur', function () {            // On blur event
        if (this.value === '') {                    // If the input is empty
          this.value = this.placeholder;            // Make value placeholder
          this.style.color = '#666666';                      // Set text to gray
        }
      }); 
    }                                                // End of for loop
  }                                                  // End showPlaceholder()
}());
```

Comment: I agree, this example looks weird. But in 2024 this polyfill is irrelevant, all major browsers support input placeholders. https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_htmlinputelement_placeholder

Comment: So learning fallback codes to support IE in 2024  as a new web developer is irrelevant?

Comment: We are talking about IE9 and below. Those are very legacy browsers, they haven’t been updated in over 10 years, and almost no one is using them. I would say in ~99.99% of the cases those browsers are irrelevant. In the last 5 years this changed drastically. Things move fast in the web.

Comment: Thanks @JSONDerulo for showing light on my confusion. It was really helpful.